# Multiple links that link to the same page

Tags: java, html, javalin

I'm creating a website for a uni project. We're using javalin, html and css ONLY. What I'm trying to do is to display a webpage which has content that changes based on what link the user pressed. For example, if a user presses on the 'US' link, a webpage with the title US and the related data pops up. While if he chooses 'MEXICO', a webpage with the title MEXICO and the related data pops up.
If you are not able to provide the code, please inform me about the implementation method.

Answer (score -2):

You can create multiple HTML pages for that, like one for the US and one for Mexico. Then, link those pages with the main page using anchor tags.
e.g:

In index.html:

`<a href="./mexico.html">Mexico</a>`

Comment: theres like 200 different countries this wont work for me :/

Comment: Oh I thought you were considering only a few countries

Comment: Well, in this case, I think you have to use a public API to get countries data in your backend, then serve it conditionally to your frontend

Comment: Like this one: `https://api.first.org/data/v1/countries`

Comment: Hm. Since OP stated they only use HTML and CSS for the frontend, JavaScript's out of scope here, hence no API calls. What about links to URLs with query parameters, like `/country?code=MX`?